# Windows service and getting current operations

Tags: .net, wcf

I need to create a windows service that monitors a folder and processes any new files it finds, so basically it'll be doing some background processing. I would also like to create a client (winform/website/etc...) that can "ask" the windows service for a list of files that it's currently running.

I was thinking about creating a WCF service and just have my client invoke a "GetFiles()" operation or something similar. I was planning to create a new thread on service start and that thread will be dedicated to processing files or some background processing.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

> I was planning to create a new thread on service start

Do you mean Windows or WCF Service start here? If it is WCF - separate thread is not necessary. WCF creates it for you if you host service in Windows Service with default bindings.

Everything else looks fine.